# How to remove $VAR2 values from $VAR1 and output the remaining values to $VAR3?

Tags: shell-script, shell, posix

**OS:** kernel 2.6.x

**Shell:** POSIX compatible shell

**Utilities:** BusyBox 1.25

**Question:** How do you remove the values in $VAR2 from $VAR1 and output the remainder values to $VAR3 ? Each value in the variables is space separated.

**Logic:**

```
VAR1="1 2 3 4 5"
VAR2="1 3 5"
for i in $VAR1
   if $i is not found in $VAR2; do
   append $i to $VAR3
   remove trailing space character
done
```

**Desired Output:**

```
VAR3="2 4"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### First, simple, but limited variant

```
VAR3=$(printf "%d\n" $VAR1 $VAR2 | sort | uniq -u | tr '\n' ' ' | sed 's/\s$//)

$ echo "$VAR3"
2 4
```

The main flaw is: it leaves only unique values from the `VAR1` variable. That is, if `$VAR1` have one value repeated few times, this value doesn't appear in the `$VAR3`, because it's not unique.

**Example:**

```
VAR1="1 2 2 3 4 4 4 5"
VAR2="1 3 5"
# the resulting VAR3 variable is empty
VAR3 = "" # because it is containing only unique values and `2` and `4` repeated few times in the `VAR1`, therefore, they are not unique.

# The right result should be
VAR3 = "2 2 4 4 4"
```

#### Second, more universal and right variant

```
VAR3=$(printf "%s\n" $VAR2 | awk -v var1="$VAR1" '
{arr2[$1] = 1;}

END {
    size = split(var1, arr1); 
    for(i = 1; i <= size; i++) {
        if(!arr2[arr1[i]]) 
            printf "%s ", arr1[i];
    }
}' | sed 's/\s$//')
```

**Explanation**

1. `printf "%s\n" $VAR2` - converts the `$VAR2` to the column - one value per line.
2. `awk ...` - removes `$VAR2` values from `$VAR1`.

   - `{arr2[$1] = 1;}` - puts all `VAR2` values (they piped to `awk` by `printf`) into the array, where values becomes the array's indexes. The `= 1` just mean **true** - this value exist. This trick give us next behaviour: the first value occurrence create array element, then, if the same value appears again, it goes to the same array index, in other words, the item doesn't changed, when the same value appears few times. Thus, in the end we are having all unique values from the `VAR2` variable. If  `VAR2="one three five"`, then `arr2` will be: `arr2[one] = 1, arr2[three] = 1, arr2[five] = 1`.
   - `END { size = split(var1, arr1);` - when input lines ended (`VAR2` processing complete), we are splitting the `VAR1` into the array - each value goes into the separate item. If `VAR1="one two three four five"`, then we will get the follow array:`arr1[1] = one, arr1[2] = two, arr1[3] = three ...`, so on. The `split` function return the size of new, created array.
   - `if(!arr2[arr1[i]]) printf "%s ", arr1[i];` - then, iterates through `arr1` items and checks, does `arr2` have index for this item. For example: `i = 1; arr1[1] = "one"` then `arr2[arr1[i]]` is this  - `arr2[one]`. This item exists, don't print it. `i = 2; arr1[2] = "two"`. The `arr2[two]` doesn't exist, so print it. Thus, we are printing all values from the `arr1`, which doesn't appear in the `arr2`.
3. `sed 's/\s$//'` - removes trailing space.

**Pros of this way compared to the first variant:**

```
    # It can process strings
    VAR1="one two three four five"
    VAR2="one three five"
    # the resulting VAR3 variable
    VAR3 = "two four"

    # It doesn't remove multiple occurrence of one value in the VAR1
    VAR1="1 2 2 3 4 4 4 5"
    VAR2="1 3 5"
    # the resulting VAR3 variable
    VAR3 = "2 2 4 4 4"
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. In the first example, $VAR3 ends up containing a newline. In the script, echo $VAR shows a single line, but at the command line, the values break to a second line.

Comment: @uihdff Fixed again :) Now trailing space removed by the `sed`. I removed previous comments, because they contained wrong information (about newlines and quoting).

Comment: @uihdff Anyway, first variant more short, but less good. It is better to use the second variant.

Comment: @uihdff No, the command substitution `$(  )` can be written on multiple lines. In this case, it starts on the first line `VAR3=$(` and ends on the last line `sed 's/\s$//')`. Just copy all code to the command line and press Enter.

Comment: How is the first line removing values from $VAR1 ?

Comment: @uihdff Not the first line removes values from `$VAR1`, but all `awk` command, written on multiple lines do it. I can add comments inside `awk` code, if you are needed.

Comment: Yes, please add comments.

Comment: @uihdff Instead comments, I did addition into the explanation section.

Comment: Is this correct ? "size" is a variable used to determine the number of iterations. "!" is used to test if arr1[i] is NOT in arr2. If it isn't, add the arr1[i] value to $VAR3.

Comment: @uihdff **1.** Yes, `size` is the amount of items in the arr1. And it is used in the `for` loop. This way we are iterating through `arr1` items - from `1` to last. **2.** Also correct - `!` is negation. `if( arr2[one] )` means - if `arr2` contains element `one`. With negation, `if( ! arr2[one] )` - if `arr2` doesn't contain element `one`.

Comment: Instead of creating another variable using "awk -v var1="$VAR1", why wouldn't you just refer to $VAR1 ?

Comment: @uihdff Because `awk` variables and `bash` variables - two different things.  You can't use `bash` variables inside the `awk` program directly. `awk` doesn't see them. So, `awk` have the option `-v awk_variable_name=value`, to assigning a variable from the outside - from the `bash`, for example. Look at here: [How do I use shell variables in an awk script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19075671/2913477)

Answer (score 3):

It looks like those are meant to be list of strings which you encode by storing them space separated in a scalar variable (assumes the strings don't contain that space character).

It would make more sense to use variables of type list/array, with shells that support them. For instance, with `zsh` and its [`${varX:|varY}` array subtraction operator](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion):

```
VAR1=(1 2 3 4 5)
VAR2=(1 3 5)
VAR3=(${VAR1:|VAR2})
```

(`VAR3=("${(@)VAR1:|VAR2}")` to preserve empty elements)

Now, if you're limited to POSIX `sh` that is without array support except for `$@`, you'll have to be more creative.

The standard command for list intersection and substraction is `comm`. But the lists have to be provided as a sorted list, newline separated and inside files whose name is passed as arguments (though `-` can be used for one them to mean stdin).

So here, it becomes awkward to use. If your system supports `/dev/fd/<n>` special files:

```
VAR3=$(printf '%s\n' "$VAR1" | tr ' ' '\n' | sort | {
  printf '%s\n' "$VAR2" | tr ' ' '\n' | sort |
    comm -23 /dev/fd/3 -
} 3<&0 | paste -sd ' ' -)
```

Or:

```
to_comm() { printf '%s\n' "$@" | tr ' ' '\n' | sort; }
from_comm() { paste -sd ' ' -; }
VAR3=$(to_comm "$VAR1" | { to_comm "$VAR2" | comm -23 /dev/fd/3 -;} 3<&0 |from_comm)
```

(that also assumes `$VAR1` contains at least one element (how would you express a list with one empty elements differently from an empty list, BTW) and that elements don't contain newline characters).

So you might as well implement it by hand. Loop over each element of the first list and look them up in the second list.

In POSIX shells, you could use the split+glob operator:

```
IFS=' ' # split on space
set -o noglob # we don't want the glob part
VAR3= sep=
for i in $VAR1; do
  case " $VAR2 " in
    (*" $i "*) ;;
    (*) VAR3=$VAR3$sep$i; sep=$IFS;;
  esac
done
```

That can't be used if there may be empty elements (like in `VAR1=' 2 3'` or `VAR1='1  3'`). For that it would be better to use a non-whitespace separator (like `|` below) for which the splitting rules are different:

```
VAR1='*|foo bar||blah' VAR2='|blah'
IFS='|' # split on |
set -o noglob # we don't want the glob part
VAR3= sep=
for i in $VAR1''; do
  # that $VAR1 split+glob invocation will split the content of $VAR1
  # into "*", "foo bar", "", "blah" while with IFS=" ", the empty
  # element wouldn't have been there as sequences of spaces would
  # have been seen as a single separator. 
  case "|$VAR2|" in
    (*"|$i|"*) ;;
    (*) VAR3=$VAR3$sep$i; sep=$IFS;;
  esac
done
```

The `''` in `$VAR1''` is to make sure `foo|` is split into `"foo"` and `""` instead of just `"foo"` for instance in POSIX shells (most, as that's a POSIX requirement) that treat `$IFS` as a field *terminator* instead of *separator*.

Or you could use `awk` instead:

```
export VAR1 VAR2
VAR3=$(awk 'BEGIN{
  n = split(ENVIRON["VAR1"], a1, /[ ]/)
      split(ENVIRON["VAR2"], a2, /[ ]/)
  for (i in a2) in_a2[a2[i]]
  for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    if (! (a1[i] in in_a2)) $(++NF) = a1[i]
  print}')
```

Comment: Thank you for the extremely detailed answer. Unfortunately, this OS does not support special files or the comm command. Is the reason this is so complicated due to having to account for various types of values ?

Comment: @uihdff, what system is that? `comm` is a standard/POSIX command. If that's using `busybox` with `comm` not enabled, the `awk` ones should work as long as `awk` has been enabled. If not, the shell only one should work as long as the `ash` variant is used for the busybox `sh`.

Comment: It's a router firmware that supports BusyBox 1.25.

Comment: @uihdff, Linux has /dev/fd, but your OS might be missing the `/dev/fd -> /proc/self/fd` symlink (in which case you can use `/proc/self/fd` instead of `/dev/fd` in the code above. But in any case, that won't help if you don't have `comm`. The other solutions should work with the default build of busybox 1.25

Comment: @uihdff, what part do you find complicated?

Comment: Just the parts appearing on the screen. :) I should have said involved instead of complicated. But it appears necessary to account for varying type of values. Could you add comments for the case statements with the non-whitespace character ?

Comment: @uihdff, check the edit, see if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
> echo $VAR1 $VAR2 | tr ' ' '\n' | sort | uniq --unique | tr '\n' ' '
2 4
```

Comment: Unquoted echo is a sure source of (future) problems. Try with `VAR1="1 * 3"`.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer accounts for the newline delimiter in MiniMax's answer. However, when executed at the command line, it needs an extra trailing newline to separate from the prompt. In the script, it wouldn't be noticed.